# Using String values in switch and StringLists in case

Tags: java, string, list, switch-statement

I have two different String lists: `firstList [a, b, c]` and `secondList [d, e, f]`. Is there a way I can use a list in a case statement?

To be clear, the intended behavior is something like this:

```
switch("a"){
    case firstList
        // some code here
    case secondList
        // some code here
}
```

Comment: You can only use primitive data types(int, byte, String, char, short) and enum values for case.

Comment: What does `switch ("a")` mean?  Are you trying to use `switch` to test whether firstList and secondList *contain* "a"?

Comment: `switch(…) { case "a", "b", "c" -> /* code */; case "d", "e", "f" -> /* code */; }`